# how to trigger a DAG with future date

Tags: airflow

I want to trigger a Airflow DAG in future so the execution date is in tomorrow.

this will help us testing a file with tomorrows date.
when I click the execute button I see an option "trigger dag w/ config" but could not find any documentation around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to "trigger with config" and change the date there, next to the calendar icon. Leave the config editor as is.

Comment: I don't see this option for airflow 2.1

Comment: @Alex looks like it was introduced in 2.2: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.0/changelog.html ("Add a calendar field to choose the execution date of the DAG when triggering it (#16141)")

Comment: This option no longer seems available in Airflow 2.7 :(

Answer (score 0):

The Airflow UI doesn't allow to specify an execution date, it always triggers "right now". However, the REST API and CLI do allow you to specify an execution date.

CLI ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#trigger)):

```sh
airflow dags trigger -e/--exec-date EXECUTION_DATE DAG_ID
# For example:
airflow dags trigger -e 2022-04-05 mydag
```

REST API ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run)):

```sh
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/mydag/dagRuns' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "logical_date": "2022-04-05T00:00:00Z"
}'
```

Comment: This wasn't true in Airflow 2.5, which did allow you to specify a run date. Apparently this was removed in some later version, since I don't see it anymore in Airflow 2.7 (I don't see any way of running a DAG with a custom config, actually!)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the run date even in Ariflow 2.7, but the DAG has to have some parameters for the "Run with Params" page to show up.

Quick and dirty solution is to have some sort of dummy parameter defined in your DAG

```
with DAG(
    "dag_name",
    schedule="30 * * * *",
    ...,
    params={"dummy": Param("---", type="string", description="dummy parameter")},    
    ) as dag:
```